# Elegant way of deleting previous drawig in Matlab GUI refresh function

Tags: matlab, user-interface

This seems to be a general question but I'm trying to make it specific.

I'm writing a MATLAB GUI, taking advantage of mouse events.

The refresh function is like this and toggle it onto `click` event:

```
function callback(obj, event)

scatter(vx, vy, 'ro');

end
```

Of course after several clicks the figure becomes a mess. I have to **delete previous drawings** during refresh.

====== main.m

```
global f
f = line(0,0);
```

====== callback.m

```
function callback(obj, event)

global f

delete f

f = scatter(vx, vy, 'ro');

end
```

======

This code works but turns ugly after I make the program more **complicated**. Actually my real version of this program is like this:

```
f.r = line(0,0);
f.l = line(0,0);
f.P.l = line(0,0);
f.P.t = line(0,0);
...
```

So here I'm wondering how to write the refresh function in MATLAB GUI that deletes previous drawings elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Use a more structured way to organize your data. Something like this:

```
% main.m
function myMain

    f = [
        line(0,0); % right
        line(0,0); % left  
        line(0,0); % P.right
        line(0,0); % P.left
    ];

    set(gca, 'UserData', f);

    % ...etc.


end

% callback.m
function callback(obj, event)

    f = get(gca, 'UserData');

    delete(f(ishandle(f)));

    f = scatter(vx, vy, 'ro');
    set(gca, 'UserData', f);

    % ...etc.

end
```

(This is just one option; there are of course many more ways to do what you ask).

`gca` could be replaced by `obj` or passed explicitly. You can also pass `f` around, or make `callback`nested`in`main`. Point is,`global` can easily be avoided, which you should do because it generally [promotes bad and risky style](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

If you insist on naming the plots, you could also use structures:

```
% ...
f.r = line(0,0);    f.P.l = line(0,0);
f.l = line(0,0);    f.P.t = line(0,0);
% ...
```

in which case you can use dynamic structure reference to delete your plots:

```
function callback(obj,event, f)

    % ...

    delete_all_plots(f);

    function delete_all_fields(f)
        fn = fieldnames(f);
        for ii = 1:numel(fn)
            field = f.(fn{ii});
            if isstruct(field )
                delete_all_fields(field);
            else
                if ishandle(field )
                    delete(field )
                end
            end
        end
    end        
end
```

But as you can see, that's unnecessarily complicated compared to the simple flat array, so I wouldn't go for this option.